# How to assign value to a variable on click event in meteor

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app I need to change the value of an array based on the item clicked.
This is how I fetch items from db.

```
    Template.templatename.vname = function(){
    return Db.find();

 }
```

On clicking a button I need to change the items in the array vname.

Can I do something like

```
'click #item1' : function()
 {
   Template.templatename.vname = function(){
    return Db.find({id : this._id});  
   }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Session` variable

```
Template.templatename.vname = function(){
    var searchId = Session.get("searchId");
    if(searchId) {
        return Db.find();
    }
    else {
        return Db.find({_id: searchId});
    }
}
```

Then

```
 'click #item1' : function()
 {
     Session.set("searchId", this._id);
 }
```

A couple of notes

- The search helper returns an array, but you're fetching a single item (_id is unique)
- You would need to clear the session variable to `null` to show all the results again.